# Check if elements in 2D Array/Matrix make a loop

Tags: java

I have a 2D Array/Matrix which represents a grid. When elements are added to the grid at a certain position, the matrix equivalent position is filled with a 1 (so where there is nothing, there is a 0).

How should I proceed to check if the elements on a grid make a loop ? (they can't connect in diagonal).

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is an example, the elements will move around.

thanks for your help

Comment: I think this is a good place to use a flood fill algorithm. That should put you on the right track.

Comment: What's your code that does not work 100% so far? Most people are glad to help with the last 5% - but not do the work for you.

Comment: @dognose my code works well to display the elements on the grid when they're moved around. But I can't find anything on how to check if they make a loop or not and I honestly have no idea on where to start. the lead given by jkeuhlen will help me start that's all I'm asking for

Comment: MatthiasGrahamSlick, Like @dognose said, you will not get a full algorithm as an answer if you don't do any work towards it. I can elaborate on the flood fill algorithm in an answer if you like, but I'm not going to write the whole thing to solve your problem for you.

Comment: @jkeuhlen I didn't formulate my question well, I wasn't expecting a full algorithm, just a lead. But yes, if you're willing to tell be a bit more about flood algorithms It'd be great

Comment: Using a complex algorithm for this will offer the best performance. An easy solution could be the usage of *backtracking* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to *query* for loops. So in this case: Find the first "1", recursivley choose a neighbor, until you reached the element you had "3" (or more) iterations before (3 is the smallest loop) - if you dont encounter another "1" to go, without moving back, just use the recursion to "undo" the latest step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause today was pizza-day I'll provide you some information about the backtracking mentioned in the comments.

The Idea of backtracking is basically to assume *every* option valid, until the opposite has been proofed.

In the worst-case you are checking every path (*not every field!*), just to figure out, that there is no loop.

It does not matter at which "1" you start.

So, the basic algorithm can be written like this (Pseudo code):

```
private boolean testSolution(Position p, Position prior, List<Position> visited){
   //return true, if our current Position solves the problem
   if (visited.contains(p)){
     return true;
   }

   //this is now visited
   visited.add(p);

   //Else: Check, which options we have at the current position
   //and check if one of the neighbors is a valid solution.
   for (Position nextP : getNeighborsOf(p)){
      if (prior == null || !nextP.equals(prior)){
         if (testSolution(nextP, p, visited)){
            //this satisfies the condition!
            //we hit a position we visited a while ago but not exactly in 
            //the prior step. -> theres at least one loop.
            return true;
         }else{
            //check next neighbor for the current position
            // (no code required)
         }
      }else{
        //moving back would end in an infinite loop. avoid that.
        // (no code required)
      }
   }

   //no neighbor working? return false to return to the "prior"
   //position, so it can evaluate other options.
   return false;
}
```

to be invoked like this:

```
if (testSolution(firstOneInTheGrid, null, new LinkedList<Position>())){
  //theres a loop
}else{
  //no loop found.
}
```

---

Edit: Because the Pizza was sooo tasty, I wanted to check if my explanation is working - it works (had to add the grid parameter to run multiple tests at once, if theres only one grid, access could be static / instance bound)

```
public class Main {


    private static int[][] t1 = {
            {0,1,1,0},
            {0,1,1,0},
            {0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0}
         };

    private static int[][] t2 = {
            {0,0,0,0},
            {0,1,1,1},
            {0,1,0,1},
            {0,1,1,1}
         };

    private static int[][] t3 = {
            {1,1,1,1},
            {1,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,1},
            {1,1,1,1}
         };

    private static int[][] t4 = {
            {1,1,0,1},
            {0,1,0,1},
            {0,1,0,1},
            {1,1,1,1}
         };

    protected static class Position{
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Position(int x, int y){
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Position [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + x;
            result = prime * result + y;
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Position other = (Position) obj;
            if (x != other.x)
                return false;
            if (y != other.y)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        test("t1", t1, new Position(1,0)); //static start position
        test("t2", t2, new Position(1,1)); //static start position
        test("t3", t3, new Position(0,0)); //static start position
        test("t4", t4, new Position(0,0)); //static start position
    }

    public static void test(String name, int[][] arr, Position start){
        System.out.println("Testing case " + name);
        if (testSolution(start, null, new LinkedList<Position>(), arr)){
            System.out.println("Loop Found!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No Loop.");
        }
    }

    public static boolean testSolution(Position p,Position prior, List<Position> visited, int[][] grid){
        System.out.println("Current: " +p);

        if (visited.contains(p))
            return true;

        visited.add(p);

        for (Position nextP : getNeighbors(p, grid)) {
            if (prior == null || !nextP.equals(prior)){
                if (testSolution(nextP, p, visited, grid)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static List<Position> getNeighbors(Position p, int[][] grid){
        //Upper bound 3 hardcoded, could be dynamic.
        List<Position> result = new LinkedList<Position>();
          if (p.x > 0){ //left position
              Position np =new Position(p.x-1,p.y);
              if (grid[np.y][np.x]== 1)
                  result.add(np);
          }
          if (p.x < 3){ //right position
              Position np =new Position(p.x+1,p.y);
              if (grid[np.y][np.x]== 1)
                  result.add(np);
          }
          if (p.y > 0){ //top position
              Position np =new Position(p.x,p.y-1);
              if (grid[np.y][np.x]== 1)
                  result.add(np);
          }
          if (p.y < 3){ //bottom position
              Position np =new Position(p.x,p.y+1);
              if (grid[np.y][np.x]== 1)
                  result.add(np);
          }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Result:

```
Testing case t1
Current: Position [x=1, y=0]
Current: Position [x=2, y=0]
Current: Position [x=2, y=1]
Current: Position [x=1, y=1]
Current: Position [x=1, y=0]
Loop Found!
Testing case t2
Current: Position [x=1, y=1]
Current: Position [x=2, y=1]
Current: Position [x=3, y=1]
Current: Position [x=3, y=2]
Current: Position [x=3, y=3]
Current: Position [x=2, y=3]
Current: Position [x=1, y=3]
Current: Position [x=1, y=2]
Current: Position [x=1, y=1]
Loop Found!
Testing case t3
Current: Position [x=0, y=0]
Current: Position [x=1, y=0]
Current: Position [x=2, y=0]
Current: Position [x=3, y=0]
Current: Position [x=3, y=1]
Current: Position [x=3, y=2]
Current: Position [x=3, y=3]
Current: Position [x=2, y=3]
Current: Position [x=1, y=3]
Current: Position [x=0, y=3]
Current: Position [x=0, y=2]
Current: Position [x=0, y=1]
Current: Position [x=0, y=0]
Loop Found!
Testing case t4
Current: Position [x=0, y=0]
Current: Position [x=1, y=0]
Current: Position [x=1, y=1]
Current: Position [x=1, y=2]
Current: Position [x=1, y=3]
Current: Position [x=0, y=3]
Current: Position [x=2, y=3]
Current: Position [x=3, y=3]
Current: Position [x=3, y=2]
Current: Position [x=3, y=1]
Current: Position [x=3, y=0]
No Loop.
```

Damn, now I provided a solution against my comment.

Advantage against bruteforce: No "0" fields are checked. So, if you are searching for a 2x2 loop time complexity remains constant, whether its a 2x2 matrix or 500Mx500M  (except the search for *any* 1)

Note: This assumes that all "1"s are connected, so nothing like this:

```
1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0
```

but you could cover this as well, by checking if all "1" fields have been evaluated at least once. - Else start another search on a "1" that has not yet been evaluated.

Comment: @MatthiasGrahamSlick Added an "Example" :-)

Comment: Well thank you a thousand times, I knew pizza could make miracles but that ... ! That's a life lesson, never underestimate pizza's powers. On a more serious note, I get an error when running your code"the field t1 cannot be declared static; static fields can only be declared in static or top level types"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Flood Fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). You can find pseudocode on the wikipedia page.
For a full example of this algorithm, take a look at the java implementation on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Flood_fill#Java).

The general idea for your design would be:

1. Find a start point (i.e. one of the 1's)
2. Look at everything around that point and see if there are any other 1's
3. Note the position you start from, flip the starting 1 into a 0 and move on to the neighboring 1's (recursively).
4. If there aren't any more nearby, see if your start position is nearby to see if you came full circle.

Comment: I've worked on it and have one final question to get it done:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485647/choose-direction-to-start-flood-fill-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to jkeuhlen's flood fill solution, you could just brute force through the matrix looking for loops using something similar to this:

```
for(int r = 1; r < intArray.length-1; r++)
        for (int c = 1; c < intArray[0].length-1; c++)
            if (intArray[r][c] == 1)
                continue;
            else if (intArray[r-1][c-1] == 1 && intArray[r-1][c] == 1 && intArray[r-1][c+1] == 1 && intArray[r][c-1] == 1 &&
                    intArray[r][c+1] == 1 && intArray[r+1][c-1] == 1 && intArray[r+1][c] == 1 && intArray[r+1][c+1] == 1)
                System.out.println("("+r+", "+c+")");
```

Might be more appropriate to the situation.

Comment: Depends on the size of the matrix. Bruteforce is bad in worst-case scenarios.