# Choose direction to start flood fill algorithm for loop detection

Tags: java, algorithm, processing

I've implemented a flood fill algorithm for matrices in my program, and I'd like to choose in which direction it starts. I want to detect loops created by elements on the grid: When there is an element at a given place on the grid, a 1 is displayed in the matrix. When there isn't anything, it's a 0. And when it is elements that won't be moved, it's a 2. The flood fill algorithm starts on a 1 and turns every 1 it encounters into a 2.
example:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Would become:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 
0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Here is my code:

```
import TUIO.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

TuioProcessing tuioClient;

// Create matrix
static int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];

// these are some helper variables which are used
// to create scalable graphical feedback
int k, l, iD, x,y;
String myType;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 600);
  noCursor();
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
}

void draw() {

  matrix [1][5]= 2;
  matrix [1][6]= 2;
  matrix [2][5]= 2;
  matrix [2][6]= 2;
  matrix [3][5]=1;

  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0; i<tuioObjectList.size (); i++) {
    TuioObject tobj= tuioObjectList.get(i);
    stroke(0);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
    rotate(tobj.getAngle());
    rect(-80, -40, 80, 40);
    popMatrix();
    fill(255);
    x = round(10*tobj.getX ());
    y = round(10*tobj.getY ());
    iD = tobj.getSymbolID();
    int taille = fiducialsList.length;
    for (int o = 0; o<taille; o++) {
      if (iD == o) { 
        myType = fiducialsList [o];
      }
    } 

    activList.add(new Fiducial (x, y, iD, myType));
    fiducialCoordinates ();
    matrix [x][y] = 1 ;

    circuitState ();
    for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
      for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[p][r] + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    // activList.removeAll(activList);
  }
  for (int[] row : matrix)
    Arrays.fill(row, 0);
}

public static class FloodFill {

  public static void resolution(String[] args) {

    solve(matrix, 2, 5, 3);

    //result
    System.out.println("-------------------"); 

    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }

  public static void solve(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int fillValue) {

    if (x>=matrix.length)
      return;
    if (y>=matrix[x].length)
      return;

    int originValue=matrix[x][y];
    matrix[x][y]=fillValue;

    // Up
    if (x-1>=0 && originValue==matrix[x-1][y])
      solve(matrix, x-1, y, fillValue);      

    // Right
    if (y+1<matrix[x].length && originValue==matrix[x][y+1])
      solve(matrix, x, y+1, fillValue);
    //south-east

    // Down
    if (x+1<matrix.length  && originValue==matrix[x+1][y])
      solve(matrix, x+1, y, fillValue);  
    //south-west

    // Left
    if (y-1>=0 && originValue==matrix[x][y-1])
      solve(matrix, x, y-1, fillValue);
  }
}
```

The algorithm is created in the `FloodFill` class.The real cases are a lot more complex so here is my problem: 
When a starting point is given, how can I prevent it to look in one direction (say on the left)? Is there a way to do this? I don't want the algorithm to "look" at the position on the left of the starting point.

It is java but used in Processing.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your goal. Flood fill is meant to fill an entire region. Are you saying you want it to only fill empty spaces in some specific direction from the origin (ex: to the left of the origin)?

Comment: I agree it is supposed to fill an area, but I don't want it to start by filling the element on its left for reasons that are specific to my project ... I just need to prevent it to go on the left from the given starting point

Comment: So you want it to fill the whole area, but you don't want the *first* new spot it fills to be the one on the left of the origin? Is it okay if the spot left of origin gets filled in later?

Comment: Yes, I want it to make a loop. To help you understand: the algorithm will turn every 1s into 2s. Each 1 in the matrix represents an element on a "grid", and I move the elements around. I want to detect if they make a loop or not, and the algorithm is perfect for this. It has to follow a "path", that can't start on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through comments, you've asked for an algorithm which allows you to check for loops. The solution below does this using a modified flood fill.

```
private static enum Direction{
    UP,
    RIGHT,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    NONE;
}

public static boolean checkIfPositionIsInLoop(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int fillValue){
    int targetX = x;
    int targetY = y;
    return fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, x, y, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.LEFT /*don't allow it to start filling to the left*/);
}

private static boolean fillReachesTargetPosition(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY,  int fillValue, Direction forbiddenDirection) {

    if (x>=matrix.length)
      return false;
    if (y>=matrix[x].length)
      return false;

    int originValue=matrix[x][y];
    matrix[x][y]=fillValue;

    int xToFillNext;
    int yToFillNext;

    boolean fillingReachedTargetPosition = false;

    // Up
    xToFillNext = x-1;
    yToFillNext = y;
    if(xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.UP)){
        return true;
    } else if (xToFillNext>=0 && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.UP)){            
        fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
                fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue,Direction.DOWN /*Just came from up- don't allow it to try filling here again*/);
        if(fillingReachedTargetPosition){
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Right
    xToFillNext = x;
    yToFillNext = y+1;
    if(xToFillNext==targetX  && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)){
        return true;
    } else if (yToFillNext<matrix[xToFillNext].length && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext,targetX, targetY, fillValue,Direction.LEFT /*Just came from right- don't allow it to try filling here again*/);
      if(fillingReachedTargetPosition){
          return true;
      }
    }

    // Down
    xToFillNext = x+1;
    yToFillNext = y;
    if(xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)){
        return true;
    } else if (xToFillNext<matrix.length  && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)){
        fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
                fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue,Direction.UP /*Just came from up- don't allow it to try filling here again*/);  
        if(fillingReachedTargetPosition){
              return true;
        }
    }

    // Left
    xToFillNext = x;
    yToFillNext = y-1;
    if(xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)){
        return true;
    } else if (yToFillNext>=0 && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.LEFT)){
        fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
                fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue,Direction.RIGHT /*Just came from left- don't allow it to try filling here again*/);
        if(fillingReachedTargetPosition){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Here's a driver to show it in action:

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    System.out.println("Show matrix with loop, before fill");
    int[][] matrix = getMatrixWithWideLoop();
    printMatrix(matrix);
    System.out.println("Found loop: "+checkIfPositionIsInLoop(matrix, 0, 2, 2 /*fill with 2s*/));

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Show matrix without loop, before fill");
    matrix = getMatrixWithoutLoop();
    printMatrix(matrix);
    System.out.println("Found loop: "+checkIfPositionIsInLoop(matrix, 0, 2, 2 /*fill with 2s*/));


    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Show matrix with small loop, before fill");
    matrix = getMatrixWithSmallLoop();
    printMatrix(matrix);
    System.out.println("Found loop: "+checkIfPositionIsInLoop(matrix, 0, 2, 2 /*fill with 2s*/));


    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Show matrix without loop, before fill");
    matrix = getMatrixWithoutLoop();
    printMatrix(matrix);
    System.out.println("Found loop: "+checkIfPositionIsInLoop(matrix, 0, 1, 2 /*fill with 2s*/));

}
```

And the output:

```
Show matrix with loop, before fill
01110
01010
01110
Found loop: true
-----------------------------------------
Show matrix without loop, before fill
01110
00010
01110
Found loop: false
-----------------------------------------
Show matrix with small loop, before fill
01100
01100
00000
Found loop: true
-----------------------------------------
Show matrix without loop, before fill
01110
00010
01110
Found loop: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I get an error "Cannot find anything named direction", but you defined it ...

Comment: You'll also need to be careful about how you use this for loop detection. If you don't appropriately choose your starting starting position, solve could show a loop even when one doesn't exist. I can post a solution that gets around this if you need it.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to reflect that you're actually looking for loop detection.

Comment: That's a great answer thank you a thousand times. It seems to be lost when there are branches: 
matrix = {
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
  {0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
  {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1},
  {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1},
  {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
 };

There is a main loop, but the branches lost the algorithm

Comment: My bad, it worked. I need to make the algorithm Depth First, would you have any documentation or advices on that ?

Comment: This is depth first- when you call this on an origin origin 1, it fills the first spot above origin 1 (origin 2). The recursive call fills the spots around origin 2 before filling the spots to the right of and below origin 1. A breadth first search would fill all of the spots around origin 1 before filling any spots around origins 2,3, and 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83622/discussion-between-matthias-graham-slick-and-augray).